# Unit testing suspend function fails for LiveData but pass for Flow

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to write unit test for suspend function that emits 2 values, first is something like Loading, second is actual data. There is some inconsistency and I don't understand why it's happening. To keep it simple, here is small example with emitting few numbers (emitted type should not matter).

```
class Foo(private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher) {

    suspend fun barLiveData(count: Int): LiveData<Int> = liveData(dispatcher) {
        (1..count).forEach {
            emit(it)
            //delay(500)
        }
    }

    suspend fun barFlow(count: Int): Flow<Int> = flow {
        (1..count).forEach {
            emit(it)
            //delay(500) 
        }
    }

}
```

Two suspend functions, first returns LiveData, second returns Flow. Otherwise those functions are same. If there is no delay, results of unit tests are different. If there is at least 1 ms delay in `barLiveData` function, unit test pass.

I have these unit tests.

```
class FooTest {

    @get:Rule
    val instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @get:Rule
    val mainCoroutineRule = MainCoroutineRule()

    val foo = Foo(mainCoroutineRule.testDispatcher)

    @Test
    fun `test barLiveData`() = runBlockingTest {
        val values = foo.barLiveData(count).asFlow().take(count).toList()
        println("test barLiveData result is ${values}")
    }

    @Test
    fun `test barFlow`() = runBlockingTest {
        val values = foo.barFlow(count).take(count).toList()
        println("test barFlow result is ${values}")
    }

    companion object {
        const val count = 5
    }

}
```

TestCoroutineDispatcher is used as Dispatcher for Foo class, MainCoroutineRule sets Dispatchers Main, resets it and calls cleanupTestCoroutines.

When I run these tests, `test barFlow` pass, `test barLiveData` fails with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: This job has not completed yet`.

If there is at least 1 ms delay in `barLiveData`  function, `test barLiveData` pass. Test `test barFlow` pass always.

Am I doing something wrong? Should test be written differently?

Thank you.

*Edit: Suggested solution.*
I still don't understand, why there is different result, but I have a solution for my problem.
When I use observerForever, I can get all values that are added to LiveData.

```
val values = mutableListOf<T>()
observeForever{
  values.add(it)
}
```

From this list it is possible to check if data states are correct and in correct order.

I am not sure, if observeForever in Unit Test is a problem or not. But in any case, here is some LiveData extension function that removes observer

```
    fun <T> LiveData<T>.getAllValues(): List<T> {
        val values = mutableListOf<T>()
        val observer = object: Observer<T> {
            override fun onChanged(t: T) {
                values.add(t)
            }
        }
        this.observeForever(observer)
        removeObserver(observer)
        return values
    }
```

This works if there is no delay in function under test. I think that should not be a problem, if production code is under test.